# How to pass parameter to object dynamically?

Tags: python

I need to schedule the function automatically by the selected days. So I used schedule for this function but I can't pass arguments to the schedule object dynamically. If anyone knows how to achieve that, please provide me the solution. Below is my code:

```
import schedule
def job(ip_id):
    print "Schedule started" + ip_id

ip_id = 1
sname = "weekly"
sched = schedule.every().monday.do(job, ip_id).tag(sname)
```

It works and scheduled on monday but when I pass the value from list, error arise.

```
import schedule
def job(ip_id):
    print "Schedule started" + ip_id
ip_id = 1
sname = "weekly"
cron = [monday, wednesday, sunday]
for i in cron:
   sched = schedule.every().i.do(job, ip_id).tag(sname)
```

How to pass value to that place is my problem ?

Comment: "What is the issue in question?" the question as a whole just makes very little sense. What are the `monday`, `wednesday`, and `sunday` in your `cron` list? What is your `jschedule.every()`? Do you want to use the values behind `monday`, `wednesday`, and `sunday` to access the `every()`, or do you prefer the variable names? None of this just seems right and we have way too little context.

Comment: `job()` can be without arguments. When it is calling it can obtain arguments from another place (where `ip_id` is stored). Or you can make closure: `lambda: joib(ip_id)` as argument of `do(..)`

Comment: @Paul-AG His question is about how to get `.every().i` to work with the variable `i`.

Comment: @Barmar yes my question is that.

Comment: @Antro Does the suggested duplicate answer your question?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen jschedule is schedule package i just renamed it and I need to pass variable values  i.e(monday, tuesday,...) dynamically after every().

Comment: @Barmar I tried it but I can't get the solution. I will work over it. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No magic here. "monday" is only name of missing attribute :)

```
import schedule

def job(*a, **k):
    pass

ip_id = 0
sname = "sname"

cron = ['monday', 'wednesday', 'sunday']
for i in cron:
   sched = getattr(schedule.every(), i).do(job, ip_id).tag(sname)
```